# How to trigger an event form parent to child

Tags: c#, events, delegates

I have a column class with 2 properties Name and Value, and another class(ColumnList) which inherit it as a collection, I want to raise an event from parent class to child class means change in column value should be triggered in ColumnList class.
below is my code

```
public class Column
{
    private string colName;
    private string colValue;

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return colName;
        }
        set
        {
            colName = value;
            if (ColumnValueChangedEvent != null)
                ColumnValueChangedEvent(null, null);
        }
    }

    public string Value
    {
        get
        {
            return colValue;
        }
        set
        {
            colValue = value;
            if (ColumnValueChangedEvent != null)
                ColumnValueChangedEvent(null, null);
        }
    }

    public event ColumnValueChangedDelegate ColumnValueChangedEvent;
    public delegate void ColumnValueChangedDelegate(object sender, EventArgs e);
}

public class AddColumn : List<Column>
{
    public AddColumn()
        : base()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Check INotifyPropertyChanged and ObservableCollection<T>

Comment: if there is any answer helped you kindly close the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What You Need To do is:
**Change The List To ObservableCollection** like follows :

```
public class AddColumn : ObservableCollection<Column>
{
    public AddColumn()
        : base()
    {

    }
}
```

then in your code u can Call it like Follows:

```
    var addColumn = new AddColumn();
    addColumn.CollectionChanged += Test_CollectionChanged;
```

press Tab Vs will generate a function Like Follows:

```
private static void Test_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
       // put what ever u need here
    }
```

****this doesn't have to be static ****

**Update:**
 If You Want To change An filed in an item:
For example Lets say you want to change the name field at `addColumn[0]`.
You do it as follows:

```
var item = addColumn[0];
item.Name = "New VAlue"; 
addColumn[0] = item.Name;
```

this code will fire the event.
Note its better to warp it in a function

Comment: Thank you, it works as required when i add a column. Now i need an event if there is a change in any item value means change in name or value in the collection

Comment: In The Replace method you can change the whole item and cause the event to fire

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you want to subscribe to `ColumnValueChangedEvent` for each added `Column` item to your `AddColumn` class?

If yes, it is not possible because `List<T>` does not provide any mechanism to tell inherited class when item is added to list.

You should create a new type which not inherits from `List<T>`. It should implement `IList<T>` or something else depends on your requirements. Then in implementation in the `Add(Column column)` method just subscribe to events.